# WebSphere 6.02 DB2 Connection Data Truncation Being Raised By Driver

Tags: java, websphere

I recently started to have problems with the db2 driver packaged with WebSphere server and has started to throw data truncation errors.  It looks like it is something on the driver side doing it because it is happening in a prepared statement while setting a parameter, and the parameter that is being set is in a where clause.

I dug into this a little bit further and found out it is using the jt400.jar which looks like it belongs to the JTOpen project.  Trying to figure out what the version of the jar is and maybe try to upgrade it.

Has anyone encountered this behavior before, and know what the cause of it is?  It is a intermittent issue that is happening on our server right now, and we have not been able to track it down.

Code Snippet

```
    public static final String SQL_UPDATE = "UPDATE " + SQL_LIBRARY + ".DBPCPFILE SET PCPTHRU = ?, PCPFEIN = ?, PCPSFX = ?, PCPNPI = ?, PCPFAX = ?, PCPEMAIL = ?, PCPPARTYN = ?, PCPACCNEW = ?, PCPCHIPYN = ?, PCPNOTFEIN = ?, PCPNOPRACT = ?, PCPNOTSITE = ?, PCPELIG = ?, PCPIMAGENO = ?, PCPXTOFEIN = ?, PCPXTOSFX = ?, PCPXFRFEIN = ?, PCPXFRSFX = ?, PCPREASON = ?, PCPPARTHT = ? WHERE PCPGROUP = ? AND PCPPROV = ?  AND PCPEFF = ?";

//WHERE CLAUSE
            //Group Number
            try {
                //BigDecimal pcpNumberOfMedicalGroup = new BigDecimal(pcpProviderTO.getPcpNumberOfMedicalGroup()).setScale(0);
                //psUpdate.setBigDecimal(parmIndex, pcpNumberOfMedicalGroup);parmIndex++;
                String pcpNumberMedGroup = String.valueOf(pcpProviderTO.getPcpNumberOfMedicalGroup());
                psUpdate.setString(parmIndex, pcpNumberMedGroup);parmIndex++;
            } catch(DataTruncation e) {
                LOG.error("Medical Group Number Is Too Large[" + pcpProviderTO.getPcpNumberOfMedicalGroup()  + "] " +
                        "Allowed Size[" + e.getDataSize() + "] Sent Size[" + e.getTransferSize() + "] " +
                                "param or col value[" + (e.getParameter()? "param" : "col value") + "]", 
                        e
                );
                throw e;
            }
```

**Stack Trace**

```
[2016-05-20 08:57:23,542] WebContainer : 2 com.acordia.common.provider.dao.DB2PCPProviderDAO ERROR - Medical Group Number Is Too Large[1828] Allowed Size[4] Sent Size[1] param or col value[param]
java.sql.DataTruncation: Data truncation
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCPreparedStatement.testDataTruncation(AS400JDBCPreparedStatement.java:3319)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCPreparedStatement.setValue(AS400JDBCPreparedStatement.java:3230)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCPreparedStatement.setString(AS400JDBCPreparedStatement.java:2868)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.InternalGenericDataStoreHelper.psSetString(InternalGenericDataStoreHelper.java:483)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.setString(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:1253)
    at com.acordia.common.provider.dao.DB2PCPProviderDAO.update(DB2PCPProviderDAO.java:425)
    at com.acordia.common.provider.businessdelegate.ProviderDelegate.copyPCP(ProviderDelegate.java:881)
    at pagecode.secure.fragments.Frag_pcpphysicianmaintenance.doEditSaveAction(Frag_pcpphysicianmaintenance.java:711)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java(Compiled Code))
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java(Compiled Code))
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java(Compiled Code))
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java(Compiled Code))
    at com.sun.faces.el.MethodBindingImpl.invoke(MethodBindingImpl.java:127)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:73)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:312)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:302)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:416)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:77)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:220)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:91)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1796)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1745)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.acordia.multiclaim.filter.PhysicianDataFilter.doFilter(PhysicianDataFilter.java:65)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:142)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:121)
    at com.acordia.multiclaim.filter.MulticlaimFilter.doFilter(MulticlaimFilter.java:233)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:142)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:121)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:82)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:883)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:90)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1937)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:130)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:434)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:373)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:101)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:566)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:619)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:952)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1039)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1498)
```

Comment: the jt400 driver jar used for communicating with a DB2 on an IBM i system.  Is your database actually hosted on an IBM i system?  Be sure that you are using the appropriate DB2 driver that corresponds to the OS your DB2 install is running on.

Comment: Yes, it is an IBM iseries server that the DB is on.  There are queries that execute fine, but I cannot seem to get by this truncation error for some of the records.  The weird thing is that it has not even tried to execute the query yet when it happens.  It is happening on a setParameter call and the parameter is in the WHERE clause.  It seems like it is something in the driver.

Comment: Is it possible the issue is intermittent because it only occurs for certain (invalid) parameters being set? If you could post a code example of data being set which reproduces the problem that would be helpful.

Comment: I have added the relevant code snippet and stack trace to the post.  Thank you for your assistance

Comment: What is the exact data being passed into `setString` and what is the definition of the parameter you are trying to set?

Comment: Medical Group Number Is Too Large[1828] Allowed Size[4] Sent Size[1] param or col value[param] 

This is the first line in the stack trace from what I have going out to the log.  1828 is the value that is getting passed in.  PCPGROUP in the where cluase is what is being set.  It is a decimal type size 7 with 0 scale.  I have tried to set the parameter as a String, BigDecimal, and Double.  They all produce the same problem.